# Доступ к содержимому ячейки GridView

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Имеем **GridView1** с **AutoGenerateColumns="False"**. Столбцы реализованы через
 **TemplateField**, вывод происходит с помощью **<%# Eval('value') %>**. По нажатию на кнопку включается следующий обработчик:

```
 protected void btnvisible_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel1.Visible = true;
        TextBox value = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text.ToString();
    }
```

Который отвечает за отображение Panel1, внутри которой некое количество **TextBox** (в коде пример только для 1 поля).

*Суть задачи:* При нажатии на заданую кнопку необходимо заполнять **TextBox** в **Panel** значениями из **GridView1**.

*Вопрос:* Каким образом получить доступ к содержимому определенной ячейки в определенной строке?

Comment: а это у вас что? `TextBox value = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text.ToString();` Извеняюсь спросить, это работает? как вы строку к контролу привести смогли?

Comment: Нет, не работает. И по-идеи не должно. Это так - крик отчаянья.